# gitab webhooks:when "Build events"was triggered,what type about json will be send?

Tags: .net, gitlab, webhooks, build-events

I want to write a webapi using .net to receive json that gitlab webhooks send when "Build Events" was triggered. I want to write a data model at .net that is same as json type. But I do not know the json type that was sent.

Could anyone tell me about the type of json that was sent when "Build events" was triggered or give me a example?